# Error when inserting rows into SQLite with Python

Tags: python, sqlite

Getting an error when trying to insert a row into SQLite table from Python.

The relevant code;

```
sql = '''INSERT INTO scr(scr=?, close_date=?, vendor=?, application=?, dev=?, tester=?, release=?)''', (issueId, closeDate, vendor, application, assignedDev, assignedTester, enterpriseRelease)
try:
    cursor.execute(sql)
    db.commit()
except Exception, err:
    print("\nFailed to insert row into table scr:\n" + str(sql))
    print(Exception, err)
```

and the error returned:

```
Failed to insert row into table scr:
('INSERT INTO scr(scr=?, close_date=?, vendor=?, application=?, dev=?, tester=?, release=?)', ('236500', '0', 'Database', 'Starbase Deleted', 'john.doe', 'jane.doe', 'None'))
(<type 'exceptions.Exception'>, ValueError('operation parameter must be str or unicode',))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sql statement is not right, try this:

```
sql = '''INSERT INTO scr(scr, close_date, vendor, application, dev, tester, release) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)'''
params = (issueId, closeDate, vendor, application, assignedDev, assignedTester, enterpriseRelease)

try:
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
    db.commit()
except Exception as err:
    print("\nFailed to insert row into table scr:\n" + str(sql))
    print(Exception, err)
```

Comment: result after making changes:
`Failed to insert row into table scr:
('INSERT INTO scr(scr, close_date, vendor, application, dev, tester, release)',)
(<type 'exceptions.Exception'>, ValueError('operation parameter must be str or unicode',))`